# For the given matrix $A$, find an invertible matrix $P$ s.t. $P^{-1}AP = J_A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 5&-1\\ 4&1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$

I have to find four things: the characteristic polynomial, the minimal polynomial. the Jordan canonical form $J_A$ of $A$ and an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = J_A$.

**Characteristic polynomial**: $(t-3)^2$, so there is a repeated eigenvalue of $t = 3$ (multiplicity 2).

**Minimal polynomial**: $t-3$ (just a guess to be honest)

Next, I know that once I find my eigenvectors, these eigenvectors will be the columns of the invertible matrix $P$.

I need to find the nullspace of $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 5-3&-1\\ 4&1-3 \end{smallmatrix} \right) = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 2&-1\\ 4&-2 \end{smallmatrix} \right) $ which yields the following:

$2x_1 - x_2 = 0$ and so $x_1\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1\\2 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$

But this is a single vector and I need a matrix.  What am I doing wrong?

If it's not clear, what I am trying to do is find my $P$ first and then use that to find $J_A$.

Comment: Ragarding the minimal polynomial, is $A-3I_2$ equal to the zero matrix?

Comment: No, it's not.  In fact, it is $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 2&-1\\ 4&-2 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$.  Is my minimum polynomial the same as my characteristic polynomial then?

Comment: Since $M$ has a degenerate spectrum (eigenvectors of multiplicity greater than one), the Jordan block matrix will be of the form $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}$ and the there will be two generalized eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector

Comment: @ALB: The matrix $({}^2_0\,{}^0_2)$ has eigenvalues of multiplicity greater than one, but its Jordan form does not have the shape you claim.

Comment: @HenningMakholm the matrix you wrote is also not OP's matrix $M$.

Comment: @SocraticaFan: You appear to be unaware of the _definition_ of what a minimal ponynomial is. Please locate that definition in your textbook or other reference material instead of just guessing wildly.

Comment: @ALB: True, it is not. But this example shows that your claim that BECAUSE the spectrum is degenerate, the Jordan form must be what you state, is a lie.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment, which referred specifically to $M$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I looked it up.  I also tried $(A - 3I_2)^2$ and did not get the zero matrix, can the minpoly have higher degree than the charpoly?

Comment: @ALB: You're ignoring my point: Simply knowing that $M$ has a degenerate spectrum is not enough to tell you that it has the kind of Jordan form you qoute, and therefore **you are wrong** when you say "Since P, Q" and P is not in fact a sufficient condition for Q. It is irrelevant what Q is in fact true -- your statement is false and misleading because you're trying to tell the OP he should have been able to conclude Q simply as a consequence of P.

Comment: @SocraticaFan: What did you get, if not the zero matrix? Please double-check your computation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't know what's going on in your personal life, but from the way you're treating both me and OP, I'd say nothing good. My claim was about the specific matrix OP is interested in and I'm sorry that you read it as being a more general claim.

Comment: @ALB: It would have been correct of you to claim "the Jordan block matrix will be of the form $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&1\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$". But you didn't just do that -- you claimed that this was  **because** there is a multiple eigenvalue, and this claimed causal connection is plainly and purely FALSE.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes I did get the zero matrix.  I see that my $J_A$ matrix should have $3$ on the diagonal and $1$ on the superdiagonal, but how would I go about finding the matrix $P$?

Comment: @SocraticaFan: The first column of $P^{-1}$ must be the eigenvector -- because that column is mapped to $({}^1_0)$ by $P$ and $J_A$ maps that to $({}^3_0)$, which $P^{-1}$ then maps back to three times that column. If we call that column $v$, the second column of $P^{-1}$ is the solution to $Ax=v+3x$.